# OpenTK 2D Engine

Tags: opentk

I'm looking for a 2D gaming engine for C#/Windows. OpenTK seems reasonable, albeit made for 3D. I didn't find anything (other than an old thread from 2008) that talks about a 2D game engine.

Are there any decent (well-supported, free) 2D game libraries for OpenTK?

Comment: DV but no comments?

Comment: I think this question goes into the "which technology to use" category (see the [FAQ]). You're just asking for a list here, without any definition of what a correct answer would look like. Since "decent" and "well-supported" are somewhat ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Try [MonoGame](https://www.monogame.net), it's a multi-platform (Windows, Android, iOS, Linux, Xbox) port of XNA and is in active development. It uses some OpenTK under the hood (for platform specific capabilities on non-Microsoft systems) but provides an easier level of abstraction for 2D game development.

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at [Duality](http://www.fetzenet.de/blog/?page_id=697). It's a complete game development framework (engine + editor) that is open source, based on OpenTK and completely written in C#. Here's a [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/duality/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6).